# Como diminuir a qualidade de uma imagem no android?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma lista de objetos que possuem um array de imagens que são um tanto "pesadas", no inicio da aplicação possuo um listView personalizado que apresenta uma imagem (icone) de cada objeto, gostaria de diminuir a qualidade dessas imagens pois quando vou deslizar sobre a lista é possivel notar lentidão, precisaria fazer uma copia de uma imagem de cada objeto para diminuir a qualidade e mostrar no listview.

Como posso fazer isso em código java?

Comment: Não seria mais indicado fazer isso fora do aplicativo? Digo, você mesmo converter as imagens para uma resolução menor manualmente, e então usá-las no aplicativo (no lugar das atuais, ou então em conjunto - mantendo duas cópias de cada imagem, uma pra exibição em miniatura e outra pra exibição normal). A conversão via software também demanda tempo e você vai acabar tendo o mesmo resultado (se não for pior).

Comment: Isso não é viável, estou criando um sistema automatizado, não posso ficar forçando o usuario a ficar editando a imagem pra poder colocar no aplicativo.

Comment: Ah, é o usuário que envia a imagem então. Sorry, não estava claro na pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso é muito comum. E, além da lentidão, você pode pegar a famosa exception `OutOffMemory`.

Para evitar isso, você pode resolver em dois (simples) passos dentro de seu adapter:

1)- Colocar todo carregamento de imagem dentro de uma `AsyncTask`. Isso faz com que você tire de sua thread principal o trabalho de carregar imagens pesadas e bloquear a experiência do usuário. E, além disso, você pode cancelar a execução dessa `AsyncTask` caso, por exemplo, o usuário de um scroll muito rápido:

Adicione um `AsyncTask` dentro da sua ViewHolder:

```
...

private class ViewHolder{
    public ImageView image;
    public AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> asyncTask;
    ...
}
```

Dentro do método `getView()` de seu adapter:

```
...

//Previnindo o recycle de view
if (holder.asyncTask != null) {
    holder.asyncTask.cancel(true);
    holder.asyncTask = null;
}

//Previnido que a imagem "pisque" caso de um scroll muito rápido;
holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.someDrawable);

final ImageView image = holder.image;

holder.asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Aqui você faz as implementações a seguir
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);       
    }
};
holder.asyncTask.execute();
```

2) Dentro de sua AsyncTask, você pode utilizar uma propriedade chamada `inSampleSize`, que faz o que o decode de sua imagem em uma resolução menor, como se fosse uma "amostra" de sua imagem. Por exemplo, uma imagem de 2048x1536 utilizando o inSampleSize como 4, produz uma imagem com aproximadamente 512x384. Essa imagem carregada utiliza apenas 0.75MB de memória ao invés de 12MB do tamanho original da imagem. Você pode utilizar essa propriedade dentro de um `BitmapFactory.Options`:

```
//Dentro de sua AsyncTask criada
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        /*Reduzindo a qualidade da imagem para preservar memoria. 
        * Aqui você pode testar a redução que melhor atende sua necessidade
        */
        options.inSampleSize = 2;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(imagePath), null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Fontes:

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

[Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

Comment: Perfeito, muito mais do que eu pedi, essa parte de carregar a imagem na AsyncTask funcionou perfeito, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com o proprio google, é aconselhavel realizar o tratamento das imagens, para que sua aplicação não exceda a memoria.

```
            // Obter as dimensões do componente na tela
            File file = new File(Caminho da sua imagem)
             int targetW = imageview.getWidth();
             int targetH = imageview.getHeight();


            // Obter as dimensões do bitmap
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

            // Determinar o quanto é necessario diminuir a imagem
            int scaleFactor = 1;
            if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
                scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
            }

            // Decodifica o arquivo de imagem em um Bitmap dimensionando para preencher o
            // ImagemView
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);



            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Desta forma vc cria um bitmap do tamanho exato do componente da tela.
Fonte: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Obrigado ctza posso utilizar esse procedimento dentro da AsyncTask como o colega tambem respondeu, vlw pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Você pode redimensionar o Bitmap:

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
// ou:
resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.3), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.3), true);
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25157279/194717

Comment: Obrigado Tony..