# Carregar imagens em listview

Tags: android

Tenho um listview com este layout

**layoutlist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Praia riviera são lourenço"
    android:background="@drawable/fundop"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/nomePraia"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nomePraia"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fotoPraia"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Coemçar a descrição ...."
    android:id="@+id/descricao"
    android:maxLength="400"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btFavorito"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btFavorito"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btFavorito"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btFavorito"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_favorite"
       android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btVerMais"
        android:id="@+id/btVerMais"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:textColor="@color/wallet_link_text_light"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bt"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**adapter.java**

```
View view;
    view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();


        holder.foto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fotoPraia);
        holder.btFavorito = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btFavorito);
        holder.nomePraia = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomePraia);
        holder.descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descricao);
        holder.bt = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.bt);
        holder.btVerMais = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btVerMais);
        holder.pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        holder.position=position;
        view.setTag(holder);

        bitmapTask = new LoadBitmapImage(view,holder.foto,width,context);
    }else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        bitmapTask = new LoadBitmapImage(view,holder.foto,width,context);
    }

    holder.pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.foto.setImageBitmap(fundoBranco);
    final ListenerItem categoria = itens.get(position);
    final int drawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(categoria.nome_foto, "drawable", packageName);

    bitmapTask.execute(drawableId);

    String desc="";
    if(categoria.descricao.length()<397){
        holder.btVerMais.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        desc=categoria.descricao;
    }else{
        holder.btVerMais.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for(int i=0;i<397;i++){
            desc=desc+categoria.descricao.charAt(i);
        }
        desc=desc+"...";
    }
    holder.nomePraia.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><i>"+categoria.nome+"<i/><b/>"));
    holder.descricao.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc));
   /* if(categoria.nome.length()>20){
        holder.nomePraia.setHeight(200);
        Log.e("entrou",categoria.nome);
    }*/
    if (categoria.favorito) {
        holder.btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite_v);
    } else {
        holder.btFavorito.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_favorite);
    }
```

A classe que carrega a imagem nessa linha `bitmapTask.execute(drawableId);`

**LoadBitmapImage.java**

```
public class LoadBitmapImage extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
private View view;
private final int width;
private Context context;

public LoadBitmapImage(View view,ImageView imageView,int width,Context context) {
    this.view = view;
    this.width = width;
    this.context = context;
    // Use a WeakReference para ter certeza que sua ImageView sera reciclada
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

// Carregando a imagem em background
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... drawableId) {
    // Aqui voce utiliza seus proprios metodos para carregar e configurar sua Bitmap
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId[0]);
    bm = bm.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, width, true);
    return bm;
}

// Quando completo, coloque o Bitmap em sua ImageView
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        AdapterListView.ViewHolder holder;
        holder = (AdapterListView.ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        if (imageView != null) {
            holder.foto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        holder.pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

Desse jeito está carregando a imagem normal , mais tem um problema . Quando passa o listview muito rápido e para em alguma imagem carrega a imagem errada e vai mostrando as imagens antes de mostrar a imagem certa, queria saber se tem como quando eu chamar a classe de carregar a imagem eu vincular a imagem a um item para que mesmo se passa rápido e tiver mais de uma imagem carregando saber em qual item colocar para não colocar a imagem no item errado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tenta colocar o objeto LoadBitmapImage dentro do seu ViewHolder.

[pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45947/como-diminuir-a-qualidade-de-uma-imagem-no-android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45947/como-diminuir-a-qualidade-de-uma-imagem-no-android#answer-45967)